# Compare data from database with php variable

Tags: php

I have one arduino (mega) and one ethernet module. I send data from the arduino to the database without problem in one table with id.

My problem is I don't know after I get data in my database how do compare data with some variable from php.

Example:
In my database I have alot id's from arduino (it's like rfid acces control) I send with rfid card one id. In database I have all id's but I wanna compare like :If number_id == $Name_student do something....

```
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM sala_v202";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td></tr>";
```

Here I have code to show all data from database but I wanna try to compare that `. $row["id"].`  to some variable saved in php.

Conclusion after all code:

```
 $Student_name1 = 1;
 $Student_name1 = 2;
 $Student_name1 = 3;
 $Student_name1 = 4;
 $Student_name1 = 5;
```

Arduino send id from rfid > 1 or 2  or something

```
if(. $row["id"]. ==  $Student_name1){
...do something
}
```

I say again it's like a timekeeping system.

If can someone help me with some advice If you need some information leave a comment If I haven't given enough information.

Comment: there shouldn't be dots in your conditional statement's row check.

Comment: I tried reading this three times, but it's not really clear what the problem is. Can you start with explaining briefly want you want to achieve *functionally* (the goal), then what you tried *technically* to achive it, and why that didn't work for you, including expected behavior, actual behavior (what is wrong about output, which error messages do you get, etc.)

Comment: Ok, tell me please If I have some data from arduino how Can I do to compare or to make one "prezent"/hour for student?

Comment: Ok I try. When you go to work you have 1 card rfid (that little card with you make in system you are prezent to work). I wanna try to make same but for the student to know who is prezent and who are not prezent. I send data from arduino to database (with insert) How can I do now to make some calendar? or something to know If that data from arduino I send who is that student and when at what hour ?

Comment: It is possible to give me you't facebook or skype to show you exactly please?

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td></tr>";
}
```

I don't know if I got your question, Try this:

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(in_array($row["id"],$arr)){
     #get the index
     $i= array_search($row["id"],$arr);
     $value=$arr[$i];
     #..do something
    }else{
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible without array  just with a variable? like search in that "row["id"] becouse If I do something ex: echo "test" he print number =  number_find

Comment: It Work thank you very much I solve with you'r code thank very much